# Why this yellow geometrical shapes appears when I add bones? I

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image: Rigging bone appear with geometrical yellow shapes]

I'm new in this field. Everything gose well but suddenly I stucked because some yellow geometrical shapes appears when I add bones.It's so frustrating. I tried some ways to fix this, changing the material size, rotate it etc. But nothing happened, I need help so badly.

Comment: I have never seen anything like this before, are you using the default scene with blender set to default settings? Does this happen when you make new file and add bone? Is there anything that is connected to the bone? Can you share your file? ... This looks like glitch done by your system, what is your GPU?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also facing same type of issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1biwhZUMnMUgmvtl3HUTgDUIPZghG9TJS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @muhammadfarooq might be a bug. When I open your file the bone looks normal. It has the orange outline as it should be (tested with Blender 3.6.2).